# Hypergeometric distribution, distribution function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function

I'm looking for a way to get a distribution function for having 1211 tokens in a bowl. I'm picking one by one, randomly out of the bowl without putting it back. And I want to have a 75% or 90% certainty to having picked a specific token (the big win). Since im not putting back any token (even if I lost) my guess is having a hypergeometric function, but I can't find anything on a distribution function to get these amount of pulls to reach a certain percentage.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use a hypergeometric distribution, it is not necessary in this case because there is only one token you are interested in.  This simplifies the probability model as follows.

Consider a bowl of $n$ tokens, one of which is winning.  We first compute the probability that you will win on exactly the $x^{\rm th}$ draw.  To do this, imagine that instead of drawing from the bowl, that you are instead taking tokens out of the bowl at random and arranging them in a line, without looking at them.  Then you pick each token sequentially from the line until you find the winning token.

Since the arrangement of $n$ tokens in a line can be performed in $n!$ ways, how many of these arrangements have the winning token in the $x^{\rm th}$ position?  Clearly, the other $n-1$ losing tokens can be arranged at will, so there are $(n-1)!$ such arrangements.

It follows that the probability that you will win on *exactly* the $x^{\rm th}$ draw is simply $(n-1)!/n! = 1/n$, and it doesn't depend on $x$--that means your chance of winning on any given draw is $1/n$, even when the draw is performed without replacement.

Consequently, the probability you win *within* $x$ draws is $x/n$.

So how many draws do you need in order to have a $p$ percent chance of winning?  You simply need the smallest $x$ such that $x/n \ge p$, or $x = \lceil np \rceil$ draws.  In your case, $n = 1211$, so to have at least a $75\%$ chance of winning, you'd need $\lceil (1211)(0.75) \rceil = 909$ draws, and to have at least a $90\%$ chance of winning, you'd need $\lceil (1211)(0.9) \rceil = 1090$ draws.

---

For completeness sake, let's revisit the hypergeometric distribution.  Again, we have $n$ tokens, but now say that $m$ of these tokens are winners.  You draw $x$ tokens without replacement.  If $W$ is the random number of winning tokens drawn, what is the probability that you get $W = w$ winning tokens?  It is
$$\Pr[W = w] = \frac{\binom{m}{w} \binom{n-m}{x-w}}{\binom{n}{x}}.$$
Then since your question deals with the case $m = 1$, $w = 1$, we find $$\Pr[W = 1] = \frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{x-1}}{\binom{n}{x}} = \frac{x}{n}.$$  And this is the probability that we win within $x$ draws, as we showed above.  However, we can also see that this model is more flexible, since if $m > 1$, we can use it to characterize the probability of winning within $x$ draws, where $W \ge 1$ is considered a win (i.e., you only need one of the winning tokens to win).

Comment: This explains so much! From just simply answering the question to now i think i unterstand the hypergeometric distribution. Id love to give this a +1 but i dont have enough reputation^^. Thank you for the detailed explenation!